# Laravel 5 returns string primary key as integer

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a settings table in my database that looks like this:

```
|    name    |    value    | validation |
|  site-name | Sample Site |   max:255  |
| site-title | Sample Site |   max:255  |
```

This is how my Setting model looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Setting extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'name';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'value'];
}
```

and the Controller.php file used for sharing the settings variable across all views:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Setting;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, AuthorizesResources, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    protected $usr;
    protected $settings;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->usr = Auth::user();
        view()->share('usr', $this->usr);

        $this->settings = array();
        $allSettings = Setting::all();

        foreach ($allSettings as $setting)
            $this->settings[$setting->name] = $setting->value;

        print_r($this->settings);

        view()->share('settings', $this->settings);
    }
}
```

the print_r is used for debugging.
For some reason, the print_r outputs:

> Array ( [0] => Sample Site )
>   instead of:
>   Array ( [site_name] => Sample Site )

It looks like $setting->name returns an integer instead of a string (the name column on the database is set as varchar).

Any ideas why it happens?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if its not integer use in model

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this.

All I needed to do is to add this line to my Setting model:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```